# Node.js HTTP request not returning full response

Tags: node.js, http, get, request

I'm making a *HTTP* request using Node's `http` module, but on `data`, the chunk returned doesn't seem to content the full request response. Here's my code:

```
var req = http.request(httpOptions, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
});

req.on('response', function (response) {
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
        callback(null, JSON.parse(chunk));
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    callback(e);
    //callback(e.message);
});

req.end();
```

Is there a way to wait for the full output before ending the request? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Where did the variable `response` come from?

Comment: I think you need a `res.end();`

Comment: I think my editor accidently autocorrected it, I fixed it for the question (it was okay in my editor).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the whole response body when the response is chunked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083914/get-the-whole-response-body-when-the-response-is-chunked)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

you should also listen for the 'end' event

```
req.on('response', function (response) {

    var data = "";

    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
        data += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function(){
        callback(data);
    })

});
```