# Node js Child Process Spawn runs whole python code every time I call

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, tensorflow, spawn

I have this code which connects Nodejs to Python script. The script contains ML models with Tensor flow backend and so on.., it basically gives a string output. I send an image URL from node js via.child process spawn to python and it gives back its recognised expression as a string. Basically I am doing facial recognition, coded in python but calling through Node js and send the string to response as JSON data(Rest API).

The problem I am facing is whenever I call spawn, it runs whole code of python and its taking so long as the python script has to load all modules if we start from the top and finally giving output.

Here is the python code

```
from gtts import gTTS
language = 'en'
#myobj = gTTS(text='Do you know the person? Yes or No', lang=language, slow=True)
#myobj.save("question1.mp3")
#myobj = gTTS(text='What is his or her name', lang=language, slow=True)
#myobj.save("question2.mp3")
import csv
import pandas as pd   
import numpy as np
#with open('database.csv','w') as f:
 # writer=csv.writer(f) 
 # writer.writerow(['Chinmay',embedded])
face_embeddings=np.array(pd.read_csv('database.csv',header=None))
face_names=np.array(pd.read_csv('database_names.csv',header=None))

from cv2 import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

from align import AlignDlib
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import os 
from torch.autograd import Variable  
from model import create_model

import transforms as transforms
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import resize 
from models import *

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from util.model import CNNModel, generate_caption_beam_search
import os

from config import config
from pickle import load
import sys

cut_size = 44
transform_test = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.TenCrop(cut_size),
    transforms.Lambda(lambda crops: torch.stack([transforms.ToTensor()(crop) for crop in crops])),
])
class_names = ['Angry', 'Disgust', 'Fear', 'Happy', 'Sad', 'Surprise', 'Neutral']
final_text=''
nn4_small2_pretrained = create_model()
nn4_small2_pretrained.load_weights('weights/nn4.small2.v1.h5')

def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])

def load_image(path): 
    img = cv2.imread(path, 1)
    # OpenCV loads images with color channels
    # in BGR order. So we need to reverse them
    return img[...,::-1]


def extract_features(filename, model, model_type):
    if model_type == 'inceptionv3':
        from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
        target_size = (299, 299)
    elif model_type == 'vgg16':
        from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
        target_size = (224, 224)
      # Loading and resizing image
    image = load_img(filename, target_size=target_size)
    # Convert the image pixels to a numpy array
    image = img_to_array(image)
    # Reshape data for the model
    image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
    # Prepare the image for the CNN Model model
    image = preprocess_input(image)
    # Pass image into model to get encoded features
    features = model.predict(image, verbose=0)
    return features
def getrecogstr( imgurl ): 

    # Path of Image
    #image_file=imgurl

    image_file = sys.argv[1]

    # Initialize the OpenFace face alignment utility
    alignment = AlignDlib('models/landmarks.dat')

    # Load an image
    jc_orig = load_image(image_file)

    # Detect face and return bounding box -
    bb = alignment.getAllFaceBoundingBoxes(jc_orig)
    net = VGG('VGG19')
    checkpoint = torch.load(os.path.join('FER2013_VGG19', 'PrivateTest_model.t7'),map_location='cpu')
    net.load_state_dict(checkpoint['net'])

    # Load the tokenizer
    tokenizer_path = config['tokenizer_path']
    tokenizer = load(open(tokenizer_path, 'rb'))

    # Max sequence length (from training)
    max_length = config['max_length']
    caption_model = load_model('model.hdf5')
    image_model = CNNModel(config['model_type'])

    for i in bb:

        # Transform image using specified face landmark indices and crop image to 96x96
        jc_aligned = alignment.align(96, jc_orig, i, landmarkIndices=AlignDlib.OUTER_EYES_AND_NOSE)

        location=(i.height()+i.width())/(jc_orig.shape[0]+jc_orig.shape[1])

        #  Finding the emotion of cropped image
        gray = rgb2gray(jc_aligned)
        gray = resize(gray, (48,48), mode='symmetric').astype(np.uint8)
        img = gray[:, :, np.newaxis]

        img = np.concatenate((img, img, img), axis=2)
        img = Image.fromarray(img)
        inputs = transform_test(img)

        #net.cuda()
        net.eval()
        ncrops, c, h, w = np.shape(inputs)

        inputs = inputs.view(-1, c, h, w)
        #inputs = inputs.cuda()
        inputs = Variable(inputs, volatile=True)
        outputs = net(inputs)
        outputs_avg = outputs.view(ncrops, -1).mean(0)  # avg over crops
        score = F.softmax(outputs_avg)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs_avg.data, 0)
    # Find the name of the person in the image

        jc_aligned = (jc_aligned / 255.).astype(np.float32)
        embeddings = nn4_small2_pretrained.predict(np.expand_dims(jc_aligned, axis=0))[0]
        print("@@")
        print(embeddings)
        matched_embeddings=1000

        for j in range(len(face_embeddings)): 
            temp=np.sum(np.square(embeddings-face_embeddings[j]))
            if (temp<=0.56 and temp <matched_embeddings):
                matched_embeddings=np.sum(np.square(embeddings-face_embeddings[j]))
                face_index=j
        print(temp)
        print('above')
        if matched_embeddings!=1000:
            face_name=face_names[face_index][0]
            print("@@known")
        else:
            face_name='Unknown'
            print("@@unknown")
            #print("Unknown Person detected. Do you know this person yes or no ?")
            #Play welcome1.mp3

            #Play welcome2.mp3 if input is yes

        final_text+= face_name+' expression is '+class_names[int(predicted.cpu().numpy())] + "."
        print("@@"+final_text)
        sys.stdout.flush()
getrecogstr()
```

Here is the Node code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 1000;
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // application/json

app.use((req, res, next) => {
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
 next();
});
app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
 const imgurl = req.query.imgurl;
var process = spawn('python', ["./final.py",
   imgurl, 
 ]); 
 process.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
   const recog_str = data.toString().split('@@')[3];
   console.log(recog_str); 
 res.json(recog_str)

 })
})


server.listen(port, () => {

 console.log("Ok");
})
```

I just want to skip that part of loading modules every time. I know we have to run the modules for them to be in memory but it's taking so long. Can do like the python script is running all the time and we can send arguments from node js in the middle of that running and call a function which can return that string?

Comment: Your problem is that your python code runs when you run your python code?

Comment: If you want to repeatedly run python, but not have repeated start-up costs, you need to implement some form of Python daemon or server that you forward requests to.

Comment: No, I don't want to run whole python code from the start I just want to call the function getrecogstrI() which needs all the modules to be loaded and its taking time to load (like 10 sec or so).

Comment: So yeah, you need to implement a python daemon or server that exposes that function.

Comment: And how do we do that? some code helps

Comment: That's too broad to answer here

Comment: You can suggest other ways of doing this, sending messages from Nodejs to ML model python in real-time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a global variable and message communication between node and spawned python process.

I got the idea from [this](https://github.com/larkintuckerllc/amqplib-rpc-example/blob/master/src/server.ts) tutorial which is regarding the message queue, but the same method can be applied here.

app.js

```js
const app = require('express')();
const uuid = require('uuid');
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var py = spawn('python', ["./face.py"]);
var globalobj = {}

//whenever any data arrives, it will be stored in globalobj.
py.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    try {
        const { id, msg } = JSON.parse(data.toString());
        globalobj[id] = msg;
    } catch (err) {
        //If data chunk received is incomplete(child process sent large output) json parse fails.
    }
});

const delay = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
    }, 4000);
});

app.get('/test', async (req, res, next) => {
    const url = req.query.imgurl;
    const id = uuid.v4();

    py.stdin.write(JSON.stringify({ id, url }) + "\n");
    await delay();

    //If no response has arrived from the child process, globalobj wont have id key.
    if (globalobj[id] != undefined) {
        res.send(globalobj[id]);
        delete globalobj[id];
    } else {
        res.status(500).send('No response from child process');
    }
});

app.listen(3000, 'localhost', () => {
    console.log(`server started on port 3000`);
});
```

The downsides are the messages which get a response after the delay will be accumulated in the global object. Also the `py.stdout.on('data', function(data){})` returns the data in stream, so if message is larger it will be split into chunks by nodejs. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243810/handling-chunked-responses-from-process-stdout-data-event)

Reason for using `\n` when writing to child stdin can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264688/how-to-flush-nodejs-child-process-stdin-write/44416999).

main.py

```py
import sys, json

while True:
    stdin = sys.stdin.readline().replace("\n", "")
    if stdin:
        data = json.loads(stdin)
        #do your computation here

        print(json.dumps({'id': data['id'], 'msg': 'your message'}), flush=True)
        stdin = None
```

When I quickly tested, it worked, but it may not work in all cases. Test this method well before using it.